# Securing JBoss admin console with SSL not working

Tags: ssl, https, console, jboss7.x

I'm running JBosss AS 7 in a domain mode. When I applied the changes to host.xml, I received the following errors.

[Host Controller] Message: JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:1.2}socket-binding' encountered

I followed this reference guide.

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SecuringAdministrationConsoleWithHttps

## host.xml

```
<management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
<server-identities>
<ssl>
<keystore path=".keystore" relative-to="jboss.home.dir" password="changeit"/>
</ssl>
</server-identities>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.domain.config.dir" />
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
                <socket-binding https="management-https"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Has anyone setup SSL with the Console? Any feedback are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that JBoss doesn't allow the <socket-binding> tag. Is there anyway to enable SSL on the Console on <management-interfaces> or <http-interface> tab? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make correct changes in configuration file on particular row and column as shown in stack trace ParseError at `[row,col]:[x,y]`

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same issue, and it's tricky for a number of reasons.  I've listed the changes to **standalone.xml** that got me going.  It goes without saying that you need to build a keystore to reference.

The most problematic part of this configuration is that the `<ssl>` element in *management.security-realms.security-realm* uses a different syntax than when configuring the `<ssl>` element in `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host">`.  I've listed both elements here to show the contrast.  You don't actually need to configure SSL for web services to get secure your console.  I added the extra detail to show how they differ.

```
    <management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl protocol="TLS">
                  <keystore path="/my/path/to/certs/my_cert.jks" keystore-password="mypass"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
            <authentication>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <management-interfaces>
        <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
        </native-interface>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
            <socket-binding http="management-console-https"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
</management>
.
.
.
<profile>
.
.
.
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
        <ssl password="mypass" certificate-key-file="/my/path/to/certs/my_cert.jks" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false" certificate-file="/my/path/to/certs/my_cert.jks"/>
    </connector>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
.
.
.
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
.
.
.
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-console-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.console.https.port:9991}"/>
```

Also, since you won't be using it, remove the old socket-binding:

```
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
```

I hope that this helps.